# query add .css if div has active class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have trouble with this jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($('#left-menu').hasClass('active')){
        console.log(true);
        $("#submenu").css("display", "block");
    };
});
```

With this function I need to add .css display block to submenu

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="active" id="left-menu">Test</a>
        <ul style="display: none" id="submenu">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        <ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="left-menu">Test 2 </a>
        <ul style="display: none" id="submenu">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And now I will describe where is problem. When is active first link everything is ok and jquery add .css display: block. But when is active second link jquery do not add .css display: block.

Can you someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context. Use class instead

Comment: @DhavalMarthak That's not a syntax error

Comment: you have ID duplication - change it to class

Comment: Also `<ul>` does not have an end tag. There is error there too.

Comment: And which ID should I change? left-menu or submenu ?

Comment: oh sorry <ul> have end tag but I wrote there with mistake.

Comment: @folpy both to get valid HTML, seems obvious isn't it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs must be unique, so use instead: (and close all UL tags)

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="left-menu">Test</a>
        <ul style="display: none" class="submenu">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="left-menu active">Test 2 </a>
        <ul style="display: none" class="submenu">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
        $(".left-menu.active").next('.submenu').show();
});
```

BTW, you could use: `$(".left-menu.active").next('.submenu').show();`

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MVNfA/)

Comment: I tried your version but it is not working. When I look at your demo it doesn't work too for me.

Comment: Updated answer, should be `next()` not `find()` my bad!

Comment: Thanks A.Wolff and others to your fast help. Your solution works exactly as I need. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will only render the first Id `id=left-menu`.

It seems like the second ID is being disregarded by the browser, as this is the output HTML:

If you really need additional identifiers on an element, you should think about using either multiple class names or data attributes to correspond to additional data.

`<a class="active left-menu">Test</a>`